# Confuse about the initial request with Cross Domain issue

Tags: cross-domain

All:

I am pretty new to cross-domain, my understanding about how Chrome works with cross-domain request is like: if user start a request on a page from one domain to another, the browser will first give a try to test if that domain provides a cross-domain service, then decide send the request out or just reject this request by showing info in the console, I am not sure if this is correct, please advice first.

If so, then the only question is when we init a request to a domain in the browser, like entering an website url in address bar, why that can not be counted for a cross-domain request, or what that request's domain is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is largely correct, so as for your question:

> when we init a request to a domain in the browser, like entering an website URL in address bar, why that can not be counted for a cross-domain request?

Simply because the "old" (or non existent if that's the first request after you open the browser) doesn't have access to the new request. It doesn't know anything about it and it can't access it, hence there's no risk of sharing or stealing vulnerable data this way, which is the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) goal.

Comment: Thanks, however I did not quite catch the point, could you give a little more detail how browser work with the first request to decide this request can be sent out? Let's say we want to visit google.com

Comment: I don't really understand the confusion, but I'll add that for all purposes navigating (either via typing an address in the address bar, following a simple link or any other way) is equivalent to closing the "old" page and then opening the new page. They don't exist simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, but this is really a little hard for me to understand,  say I am the browser, when a  user enter a URL, and ask me to send out. Then here is the question, because right now, there is no "current domain"( I just start on local desktop), Why I believe this is within same domain and send it out anyway?

Comment: Again, same origin policy is not about navigation at all (which is what happens when a user enters a URL at the address bar), and so the process of cross-origin check is irrelevant and doesn't take place. Only when one page wants to interact with another page this becomes relevant.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. I thought init request also belong to one page to another page interaction before.